# multiple groups of query in 1 statement using OR

Tags: mysql

I am trying to identify low "scores" added to a table where other scores are high. Put simply, I want to know where someone has scored 1 for a single question but 2 or above for the others. I came up with this;

```
SELECT * FROM `review_survey`, `users` WHERE review_survey.user_id =users.kituser_id AND 
(review_survey.s1 < 2 AND review_survey.s2 >= 2 AND review_survey.s3 >= 2 ) 
OR (safeguard_review_survey.s1 >= 2 AND safeguard_review_survey.s2 < 2 
AND safeguard_review_survey.s3 >= 2) AND `complete` = 1 AND users.account = 1
```

But it returns a massive dataset that can't possibly be accurate.

Where do I start?

Comment: a good start would be using GROUP BY

Comment: You should start with providing sample data and the desired result set.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

To begin wiht, please try this first:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    `review_survey`, `users` 
WHERE 
     review_survey.user_id =users.kituser_id 
AND (  --<-- missing parenthesis
      (review_survey.s1 < 2 AND review_survey.s2 >= 2 AND review_survey.s3 >= 2 ) 
      OR 
      (safeguard_review_survey.s1 >= 2 AND safeguard_review_survey.s2 < 2 AND safeguard_review_survey.s3 >= 2)
    )   --<-- missing parenthesis
AND `complete` = 1 AND users.account = 1
```

Better yet, move things around so you have

```
 condition AND condition2 AND condition3 AND ( condition4 OR condition5)
```

As of now it's very likely AND and OR don't work as you'd expect